# How can I load only a subset of Foundation 4 JS files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, zurb-foundation

I'm running a Rails 3 app and am including the zurb-foundation gem to bring in Foundation 4. I noticed (in my local dev env) that every single Foundation JS plugin/lib is being loaded. I'm only using a couple, or so. My question is, how can I customize which Foundation JS files are loaded? I'd like to only load a subset of the Foundation JS files.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By requiring foundation

```
//= require foundation
$(document).foundation();
```

it requires all of these:

```
/*
=require foundation/foundation
=require foundation/foundation.alerts
=require foundation/foundation.clearing
=require foundation/foundation.cookie
=require foundation/foundation.dropdown
=require foundation/foundation.forms
=require foundation/foundation.joyride
=require foundation/foundation.magellan
=require foundation/foundation.orbit
=require foundation/foundation.reveal
=require foundation/foundation.section
=require foundation/foundation.tooltips
=require foundation/foundation.topbar
=require foundation/foundation.interchange
=require foundation/foundation.placeholder
*/
```

Instead, just require what you want.

```
=require foundation/foundation
=require foundation/magellan
$(document).foundation();
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jesse! How silly of me not to figure that one out. :P

Answer (score 1):

As the latest version of foundation-rails (5.5.0)

```
//= require foundation/foundation
//= require foundation/foundation.magellan

$(document).foundation();
```